# How to pass variables from model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting that results variable is undefined in my Ajaxcont Controller. I am not exactly sure how to pass $results back from the model into the controller. i just want my $results array to hold all the value that was retrieved by the query. What am  i doing wrong?

---

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajaxcont extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("ajax_model");
    }

    function index()
    {
        $search = $this->input->post('search', TRUE);
        $like_search= '%' .$this->db->escape_like_str($search) . '%';
        $query=  $this->ajax_model->search_course($like_search);

        if ($query)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {

                //$course_name_highlighted = str_ireplace($search, '<b>' .$search . '</b>' , $row->full_name); 

                $start = stripos($row-> Course_Name, $search);
                $length= strlen($search);
                $new_search = substr($row->Course_Name, $start, $length);
                $course_name_highlighted = str_ireplace($new_search, '<b>' .$new_search . '</b>' , $row->Course_Name); 
                $results[]= array(
                    'Course_Name' => $row->Course_Name,
                    'FirstName' => $row->FirstName,
                    'LastName' => $row->LastName,
                    'COURSE_ID' => $row->COURSE_ID,
                    'course_name_highlighted' => $course_name_highlighted
                    );
            }
        }

        if ( $this->input-> is_ajax_request())
        {
            $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            $this->output->set_header("Expires:Mon, 4 Apr 1994 04:44:44 GMT");
            $this->output->set_header("Content-type:application/json");

            echo json_encode($results);
        }
        else 
        {
            $data['results'] = $results;
            $this->load->view('ajax_search', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Axaj_model code:

```
<?php

Class Ajax_model extends CI_Model 
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search_course($like_search)
    {
        $this->db->select('FirstName, LastName, COURSE_ID, Course_Name, Semester,Time,Book, SECTION_ID');
        $this->db->from('Section');
        $this->db->join('faculty', 'faculty.FACULTY_ID = section.FACULTY_ID');
        $this->db->like('Course_Name', $like_search);
        $this->db->order_by('Course_Name');
        $query = $this -> db->get();

        //If it is all correct
        $results=array();

        if($query -> num_rows() > 0 )
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your results array should be declared outside of the 'if' block, now it is undefined at the point where you echo it

Comment: Are you getting this when there are no query results?

Comment: Could you share with us where in your code you get the "variable is undefined" notice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is returning a multi-dimensional array. so you should use instance to retrieve the data.

**MODEL**

```
$results=array(); // you don't even have to declare it

if($query -> num_rows() > 0 )
{

 $result= $query->result();
return $result;

 }

else
{
    return false;
}
```

**Controller**

```
function index()

 {

  $search = $this->input->post('search', TRUE);
  $like_search= '%' .$this->db->escape_like_str($search) . '%';
  $query['result']=  $this->ajax_model->search_course($like_search);

if ($query)
{
    foreach($query['result'] as $row)
    {
     //stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: edited a small mistake..check the code now and report the output

Comment: now i'm getting Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try `foreach($result as $row)`

Comment: if you want to check the output returned from model, add `print_r($query['result'])` after $query['result']=  $this->ajax_model->search_course($like_search);

Comment: thanks for trying but it's still not returning anything nor is the print statement working.

Comment: Err..`print_r` isn't working?! are you sure that your mysql query is returning any data in your model?

Comment: what's the correct command to send the form to the controller, currently i was using **<form method="post" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>">**

Comment: @Undermine2k maybe it is returning 'false' .That should be the only reason for `print_r()` not returning anything

Comment: @Undermine2k _current page_ ? So you don't have a view file,huh? In codeigniter `form_open_multipart('controller_filename')` (produces <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/controller_filename" />) is used for form opening.. Refer [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your results array should be declared outside of the 'if' block, now it is undefined at the point where you echo it. Add this:

```
$results = array();
```

at the beginning of your function 'index'.

You should read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: yes, you are correct i left out this line, however that it still does not return any data. I think i'm not returing data back from my model correctly how can i debug and see what i'm returning?

Comment: @Undermine2k No need to declare that. You are not retrieving the result right.As it is a multi-dimensional array, you have to use instance

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the index function you should declare the result.

```
function index(){
     $result = array ();
}
```